# SQLAlchemy Inserting into Existing Table, default item value for columns unspecified in Model

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Let's say that I have an existing table that I want to map to that contains 10 columns; however, I only care about writing to 3 of these columns, via a specified Model.

If I insert a record according to this model, the values under columns not included in the Model will result to NULL.

Is there a way in SQLAlchemy to specify the default value of a column to not be NULL? Perhaps 0 for an integer or '' for a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SQLAlchemy does not know about the columns, you have to setup default values on the server side. Otherwise, specify all the columns and [define the default values](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default).

```
class MyModel(Base):
    foo = sa.Column(sa.String, default='bar')
```